# Knockout JS overwriting all values with the last value in foreach binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my KnockoutJS app, I am looping over an observable array and displaying some stuff like this:

```
<div id="user-list-container" data-bind="foreach: users">
    <div class="row order-line list-row">

        <div class="medium-7 small-10 columns">
            <i class="fi-torso tip-right"></i>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="text: user().name"></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="text: accountId"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="medium-3 columns">
            <a href="#" class="button split tiny info radius">
                <i data-bind="text:role"></i>
                <span data-dropdown="leftDrop" data-options="align:left"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="medium-2 small-2 columns">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: $root.deleteRole"><i class="fi-trash" title="@Texts.Remove"></i></a>
        </div>

        <ul id="leftDrop" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
            <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.makeForeman">Foreman</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.makeWorker">Worker</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine and all the elements are shown, but when I click one item to operate on that particular item, each item then has the value of last item in the array.

In my Javascript function:

```
  self.makeWorker = function (user) {

    var project = self.selectedProject();

    var account = self.accounts.findByKey(user.accountId);

    var ur = user;

    console.log(user);

    console.log(this);

    if (project.role() != "Worker") {
        var data = {
            role: "Worker",
            organizationId: project.organizationId,
            projectId: project.id,
            accountId: user.accountId
        }

        TippNett.Project.ChangeRole(data, function (result) {

            project.users.findByKey(user.id).role("Worker");

            ur.role("Worker");

            account.roles.findByKey(user.id).role("Worker");

        });
    }
}
```

The value passed to the function is always the last value in 'users' observable array.

Any input on why this is happening? See the image for more briefing:

[image]

Comment: what findByKey function are you using?

Comment: What does the rendering for your drop down buttons? Does the deleteRole work ok?